# Mysql output format in Bash Script

Tags: bash, shell-script, awk, mysql

I'm writing a bash script where I'm using mysql query in that script where the format which I'm getting is quite different.

**Query:**

```
root@debian:~# mysql -u root -ptoor super_market -h 0 -e "select * from items;" 
+---------+------------+--------+-------------+-------+
| item_id | item_name  | weight | brand       | price |
+---------+------------+--------+-------------+-------+
|       1 | Milk       |   2.00 | Nestle      |  2.00 |
|       2 | Cheese     |   2.50 | Amul        |  6.00 |
|       3 | Chips      |  25.00 | Lays        |  3.00 |
|       4 | Coke       |   5.00 | Coke Cola   |  3.50 |
|       5 | Engage     |   5.00 | Deo         |  3.50 |
|       6 | Engage     |   5.00 | Deo         |  3.50 |
|       7 | Ear phones |   4.00 | Skull Candy | 32.30 |
+---------+------------+--------+-------------+-------+
```

formatted using **column -t** command the output format is getting aligned

```
root@debian:~# mysql -u root -ptoor super_market -h 0 -e "select * from items;" | column -t
item_id  item_name  weight  brand   price
1        Milk       2.00    Nestle  2.00
2        Cheese     2.50    Amul    6.00
3        Chips      25.00   Lays    3.00
4        Coke       5.00    Coke    Cola   3.50
5        Engage     5.00    Deo     3.50
6        Engage     5.00    Deo     3.50
7        Ear        phones  4.00    Skull  Candy  32.30
```

**Bash Script**
the bash script which I tried using the above command

```
root@debian:~# cat test
#!/bin/bash

while read -r output;
do
    echo $output | awk '{print $4}'
    #do something
done< <(mysql -u root -ptoor super_market -h 0 -e "select * from items;" | sed 1d |column -t)
```

**output**

```
root@debian:~# ./test
Nestle
Amul
Lays
Coke
Deo
Deo
4.00
```

But  the **Expected Output:**

```
Nestle
Amul
Lays
Coke Cola
Deo
Deo
Skull Candy
```

Yeah! you can say use **select brand from items**. This is for example in real time I'm using quite different command.

Any Hint or Help ?

Comment: You're explicitly excluding `brand` with your call to `sed 1d` which strips the header from the output.  Try removing that from the pipeline.  Also, for the love of science, why are you running random bash scripts as root?

Comment: @DopeGhoti edited. And its a test machine Nothing to worry.

Comment: Tell `awk` that your field separator is a tab (`^I`).  The problem is that `Ear phones` is looking like two fields because a space (by being a non-endline whitespace character) is by default a field separator.

Comment: @DopeGhoti I tried that too getting a blank output

Answer (score 3):

Use `mysql` with the `-t` flag, to get the output you get from a query in mysql directly as your bash output.

Afterwards you can use `sed` or `awk` to clean up the delimiters, to remove the horizontal lines and the `|`'s.

Answer (score 2):

output of mysql is tab delimited. `column` replaces tabs with spaces breaking your input.

```
#!/bin/bash

while read -r output;
do
    # use double quotes with "$output" to avoid conversion
    # of tabs to spaces and set awk's Field Separator to "\t"
    echo "$output" | awk -F"\t" '{print $4}'
    #do something
done< <(mysql -u root -ptoor super_market -h 0 -e "select * from items;" | sed 1d)
```

test run:

```
root@c2:~# mysql -u root -ptoor super_market -h 0 -e "select * from items;"
+---------+------------+--------+-------------+-------+
| item_id | item_name  | weight | brand       | price |
+---------+------------+--------+-------------+-------+
|       1 | Milk       |      2 | Nestle      |     2 |
|       2 | Cheese     |    2.5 | Amul        |     6 |
|       3 | Chips      |     25 | Lays        |     3 |
|       4 | Coke       |      5 | Coke Cola   |   3.5 |
|       5 | Engage     |      5 | Deo         |   3.5 |
|       6 | Engage     |      5 | Deo         |   3.5 |
|       7 | Ear phones |      4 | Skull Candy |  32.3 |
+---------+------------+--------+-------------+-------+
root@c2:~# ./test.sh 
Nestle
Amul
Lays
Coke Cola
Deo
Deo
Skull Candy
root@c2:~#
```

Comment: I got the output as blank enteries

Comment: try to comment out `| awk...` to see what you get.

Answer (score 0):

This is a **very dirty** and hacky solution, but you can use the dot (`.`) as the separator since you have floating point numbers on each side.  You can call `awk` as follows

```
awk -F '.' '{a=gensub(/^[0-9]*\s*|\s*[0-9]*$/,"","g",$2); print a}'
```

in the script and it shall print only the brand.

There will be extraneous spaces in the middle of the brand names but you can extend the `awk` script to cope with that as well:

```
awk -F '.' '{a=gensub(/^[0-9]*\s*|\s*[0-9]*$/,"","g",$2); b=gensub(/\s+/," ","g",a); print b}'
```

`awk`'s `gensub` function is a very powerful tool for such kinds of problems.   Although this specific example is dirty, i believe, that knowing how to use `gensub` ([the manual is quite decent](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/String-Functions.html)) will allow you to solve similar problems with ease.

---

The above is `GNU awk` (`gawk`) specific.  Old school unix systems (`AIX`, `HP-UX`) have no `gawk`.  Funny enough, for some unknown reason, `debian` also has no `gawk` by default.  `debian` has `mawk` as the default `awk` installed.  Here is a `mawk` version:

```
awk -F '.' '{gsub(/^[0-9]*\s*|\s*[0-9]*$/,"",$2); gsub(/\s+/," ",$2); print $2}'
```

`mawk` has not `gensub`, it only has `gsub` (global substitution).  `gsub` is vastly inferior to `gensub` because it does not return its substitution.  If you are using `debian` and need `awk` often i strongly recommend installing `gawk` (it is in the main repo).

Comment: root@debian:~# mysql -u root -ptoor super_market -h 0 -e "select * from items;" -s | column -t | awk -F '.' '{a=gensub(/^[0-9]*\s*|\s*[0-9]*$/,"","g",$2); b=gensub(/\s+/," ","g",a); print b}'
awk: line 2: function gensub never defined
awk: line 2: function gensub never defined
root@debian:~#  I'm getting this error

Comment: Jolly dee... `debian` has `mawk` as the default `awk`.  Still doable but even dirtier.  As i mentioned in the edited answer, i strongly recommend installing the `GNU awk`.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to use `column` tool as your table is really done. Try using `awk` with the common delimiter `|`.

You can do the following in your `echo` line

```
echo "$output" | awk -F'|' '{print $5}'
```

So it ends as

```
#!/bin/bash

while read -r output;
do
    echo $output | awk '{print $5}'
    #do something
    done< <(mysql -u root -ptoor super_market -h 0 -e "select * from items;" | sed '1,2d')
```

Answer (score -1):

```shell
mysql -N -B  moodle -e  "select id from mdl_course;"
```

output

```shellsession
abcd@pqrs:~/backup/script $ mysql -N -B  moodle -e  "select id from mdl_course;"
1
2
4
5
8
9
10
11
12
14
16
17
3
6
7
15
```

Comment: From the question, *"you can say use select brand from items. This is for example in real time I'm using quite different command"*